# how can i make the virtualbox recognize the inbuilt bluetooth adapter of my laptop

Tags: bluetooth, virtual-machine, android-x86

i need some help to make sure that my VM have recognized the inbuilt bluetooth adapter from the laptop

it is an 2 in 1 laptop that i installed an Android x86 iso in the VM, it runs everything well, but the bluetooth it doesn't recognize properly i tried the method of activating port on the virtualbox settings, it did turned on inside the VM but doesn't show any option to connect to the device that i need, if i can't connect the inbuilt adapter, is there a way to put the connection from the host to the guest OS ??? since now thanks for your help and have a great day !